# Jquery validation minlength not working with remote rule

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate a form using jquery validate. using version 1.11

I've set up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/longestdrive/Raagr/4/

The remote function in my app and the fiddle seems to ignore all other rules for example required and minlength. Appreciate the remote function wont work in fiddle.

But in both the app and fiddle - with remote I can submit the form even though the field is set to required and I have a min lentgh set:

Here's the html for the basic field:

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST">
<label class="span1" for="ticket">Ticket Number *</label>
<div class="input-append no-margin span3">
    <input id="ticket" name="ticket" class="input-medium" type="number" required="required">
</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

And here's the basic validation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//attach validation to Form - should work with edit and create forms

$('#myForm').validate({
    debug: false,
    ignoreTitle: true,
    rules: {

    ticket: {
        minlength:4,
        remote: {
            type:"POST",
            data: { reservation: function() {
                return $( "#reservation_id" ).val();
                }
            },
            url:'/ticketaudits/validateTicket',
        }
    },

});
```

});

Not sure what the problem is or how I can validate. Basically I'm trying to make sure ticket is 4 characters long and ideally not do a remote call until it's 4 chartacters long

All help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: where is "#reservation_id" you have used in your Jquery?

Comment: Hi. This is another element in the page. The remote validation works correctly as long as there's an entry on the field - but remote and minlength and required don't seem to work together?

Comment: i saw ur fiddle there are some errors in your jquery code.. check those by using JSHint and update with bugless code.. maybe then i can help you out :)

Comment: mmm. I clicked jshint and it came up with valid script - also checked in my editor and all valid - which bits are wrong in the fiddle - maybe that's the reason it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

As per the result of the discussion that went through comments and screen shot that has been deleted by moderator as he didn't find it useful for the community..

Here's the summary..
These were the errors in your fiddle:
[image]

And this is the Jquery you should be using:

```
$('#myForm').validate({
        debug: false,
        ignoreTitle: true,
        rules: {
            ticket: {
                minlength:4,
                remote: {
                    type:"POST",
                    data: { reservation: function() {
                        return $( "#reservation_id" ).val();
                        }
                    },
                    url:'/ticketaudits/validateTicket'
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this works, the way you need it :)